# Calculating $\mathbb{E}(\tau)$ and $\mathbb{E}(W_\tau)$, where $\tau=\sup\{t\leq1:W_t=1\}$ is the last hitting time

Tags: expected-value, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

I wish to calculate $\mathbb{E}(\tau)$ and $\mathbb{E}(W_\tau)$, where $\tau=\sup\{t\leq1:W_t=1\}$ (i.e. the last hitting time).

In a [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4279655/showing-that-sup-t-leq1w-t-1-is-not-a-stopping-time), we determined that $\tau$ is not a stopping time, and so, unlike the case for the first hitting time $\inf\{t\leq1:W_t=1\}$, the optional stopping theorem cannot be used. How would $\mathbb{E}(\tau)$ or $\mathbb{E}(W_\tau)$ then be calculated? I'm guessing the reflection principle should be used, but I can't think of how to bring it in (particularly to capture the distribution of $\tau$).

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Hint: With the conventions in your previous question, $W_\tau$ is a Bernoulli random variable.

Comment: @ChrisJanjigian Hi, thanks for the comment. How is it so? Isn't it Bernoulli only at $t=0$?

Comment: Brownian motion is continuous, so $W_\tau = 1$ if there exists $t \in [0,1]$ with $W_t = 1$. If no such $t$ exists, then $W_\tau =  W_0 = 0$. This is a Bernoulli(p) random variable, with $p=P(W_t = 1 \text{ for some }t \in [0,1]).$ E: Since the question has now changed, computing $\mathbb{E}[\tau]$ is harder. For that, try thinking about the time reversal $\tilde{B}_{t} = B_{1-t}$, for which $\tau$ is a stopping time.