# Difference between running maximum and reflected Brownian motion

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion

Let $(B_t)_{t > 0}$ be a Brownian motion and let $M_t = \sup_{0 \leq s \leq t} B_s$. I was wondering whether $M_t - |B_t|$ was a Brownian motion as well ? If so, why ?

From [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1176640/running-maximum-of-brownian-motion-and-reflected-brownian-motion) question, I would naively expect $M_t - |B_t|$ to behave like $B_t$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $x>0$, we have the disjoint union
$$\{B_t<-x\}=\{M_t-|B_t|<-x\} \cup \{-x> B_t \ge-x-M_t\}$$
so
$$P[B_t<-x]>P[M_t-|B_t|<-x] \,.$$

Addendum: Note that
$$\{-x> B_t \ge-x-M_t\} \supset \{2>B_{t/2}>1\}\cap \{-x>B_{t}>-x-1\}$$
and using the Markov property and the monotonicity of the Gaussian density,
$$P[ 2>B_{t/2}>1 \; \text{and} \; -x>B_{t}>-x-1]$$
$$ \ge 
 P[2>B_{t/2}>1] \cdot \inf_{h\in [1,2]} P[-h-x>B_{t/2}>-h-1-x]  $$ $$
=
 P[2>B_{t/2}>1] \cdot P[-2-x>B_{t/2}>-3-x] >0\,.$$

Comment: Thank you ! I'm just not sure on how to justify properly that the second set in the union has a nonzero probability. Would you mind clarifying this last step ?

Comment: @Desura Is it clear now? I added an explanation.